# authentication problem on windows vista (cookie is getting written but httpcontext.current.user is null)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

authentication problem on windows vista (iis7) (cookie is getting written but httpcontext.current.user is null)

Comment: Don't repeat the title in the description tab. Elaborate on the issue so that someone can understand the issue & guide you.

Comment: You're gonna need to provide a lot more info if you want any help.  Why should we take the time to craft a good answer if you won't take the time to craft a good question?
Anyway, as an early guess you might check if anonymous logins are allowed in IIS.  Maybe you've already checked and confirmed that isn't the case but since you were so sparse with problem details...

Comment: During development or a deployed site?  Are you using Forms Authentication or Windows Authentication?  We can't see your code so we have no basis to provide any answer without a lot more information as Ganesh and Yadyn have already said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to change IIS7 mode from Integrated Pipeline to "Classic".

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to change the Managed pipeline mode to "classic" :)